# Mass movement of reports

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have a requirement wherein multiple reports from different report folders are to be moved to a new Report folder. The number of reports is huge(in thousands). I've tried it using eclipse IDE but it is more or less the same effort as moving reports one by one.
Is there a way this can be achieved through automation or App Exchanges apps? Please help if possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this, http://youraveragesalesforceadmin.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/mass-moving-reports-from-one-folder-to.html, it is recommending the Eclipse IDE as well, though it looks quite straight forward, what is it that is causing it to be more or less the same effort for you?

Comment: the number of repoorts is around 5000. and not all reports from each folder have to be moved or deleted. so i was wondering an appExchange product exists?